# Jwt Token generated without . Dot

Tags: oauth, jwt, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

I have generated JWT token but it gets generated without .

But went through some documents it is saying that jwt token is having 3 parts seperate by dots but my token not contains any dot in jwt string but gets validated

It gets validated is this valid or not?

Comment: If it has no dots, it's probably not a JWT. Why do you think it's a JWT when it doesn't look like one? It's probably just a normal opaque token, but as you don't show any code or the token itself, it's hard to tell. A JWT is a specific format for a token, but not every token is a JWT.

Comment: please include a sample token in your question